# acts_as_votable redirecting when trying to vote up/vote down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've problem with acts_as_votable gem. I have simple forum app and I want to have feature to vote up and down posts. I used for this acts_as_votable gem. I've added to posts controllers two methods:

```
def upvote
    @post = post.find(params[:id])
    @post.liked_by current_user
    redirect_to forum_topic_path(@post.topic.forum, @post.topic)
  end

  def downvote
    @post = post.find(params[:id])
    @post.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to forum_topic_path(@post.topic.forum, @post.topic)
  end
```

My routes is :

```
  resources :topics, except: :index do 
    resources :posts do 
      member do 
        put "like", to: "posts#upvote"
        put "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"
      end
    end
  end
```

And in my topic show action view i have the followings links:

```
= link_to "Upvote", like_topic_post_path(post.topic.id,post.id, method: :put) 
= link_to "Downvote", dislike_topic_post_path(post.topic.id,post.id, method: :put)
```

When I'm trying to click upvote or downvote i have been redirected to:
`http://localhost:3000/topics/104/posts/55/like?method=put` and i have following error:
No route matches [GET] "/topics/104/posts/55/like"
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try "GET" method instead of "PUT" as shown below,

```
resources :topics, except: :index do 
    resources :posts do 
      member do 
        get "like", to: "posts#upvote"
        get "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: It's not working. I have the following error:undefined local variable or method `post' for #<PostsController:0x007f3ebd021068>. The error is on line:
@post = post.find(params[:id])

Comment: First letter of table name should be caps as like Post.find

Comment: Now everything is ok but when I clicked upvote or downvote it not working. Post still have 0 votes

Comment: Did you add "acts_as_votable" in your post model?

Comment: Yes I've added, i don't know why this not wokring

Comment: I think that the bay will be implement my own simple voting system but thank's for help

Comment: Are you logged in? If current_user is nil then it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the PostsController code for redirect to:

`redirect_to :back`

If you are using Rails 5 this is better:

`redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)`